# How to Exclude Files and Folders from Volume Shadow Copy (VSS) Backups

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, vss, vssadmin

I've been using **Volume Shadow Copy (VSS)** to create backups of my files and folders. However, I've encountered a situation :

I need to ***exclude*** specific files and folders from **Microsoft built-in Volume shadow Copy** to save storage space and time.
Since VSS is enabled for the drive, there are few unwanted folder / files that are being backed up by VSS and If I delete them all other shadow copies of other files (of previous versions) might be lost.

Here are a few details about my setup:

Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2
Volume Shadow Copy:
Provider name: 'Microsoft File Share Shadow Copy provider'
Provider type: Fileshare
Version: 1.0.0.1

Provider name: 'Microsoft Software Shadow Copy provider 1.0'
Provider type: System
Version: 1.0.0.7

I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the process of excluding files and folders from VSS backups. What are the steps involved, and are there any best practices I should be aware of?.

I did search in Google and found some articles, but none of them solved my issue.

Here are few links that I have gone through.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/excluding-files-from-shadow-copies#:%7E:text=The-,FilesNotToSnapshot,-registry%20key%20is) provides FilesNotToSnapshot registry key can be used to exclude files but it is developers specific.